# IntelliJ IDEA path to current caret position (function/class) in JS files

Tags: javascript, java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 Community edition and in Java files it shows me the path from the file to the current caret position:

[image]

Is there any way to have the same bar for JS files?

**UPDATE:**

*this feature has been introduced with IDEA 2017.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such functionality was added for Java language only in 2016.2.

For JavaScript it is not yet implemented.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7386 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to be notified on any progress.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I just need to wait until this feature is added... But do you know something like that? I mean another ways to quickly determine in what function caret is positioned now?

Comment: Structure tool window? With "Scroll from Source" option enabled (not 100% sure if it's implemented for JavaScript (but it should) .. as it's all needs to be implemented  on per language basis separately).

Comment: Can't get how to use it, and IDEA's Find Action didn't find anything like "Scroll from source"...

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/n7boaekkr/ -- `Find Action` will not find such option as it's tool window specific and not global setting. Proper name is "Autoscroll from Source". The idea is -- it should focus the method/function where cursor is located .. so in *some sense* it can be partially similar to breadcrumb.